# Given an array of numbers, return an array of numbers which contains 1st number, Sum of next 2 numbers (2nd, 3rd), Sum of next 3 numbers(4th,5th,6th)

Tags: javascript

Given an array of numbers, return an array of numbers which contains 1st number, Sum of next 2 numbers (2nd, 3rd), Sum of next 3 numbers(4th,5th,6th)

```
let num = [1, 5, 7, 2, 4, 9];
let result = [];
function sumOfIntegers(num) {
result.push(num[0]);
  for(let i=1; i<num.length; i=i+3){
  let prevNum1 =  num [i]
  let prevNum2 = num [i+1]
  result.push(prevNum1 + prevNum2);
  }
  //console.log(result);
return result[];
}

sumOfIntegers(num);
```

Comment: Hey @anaya your question will probably get flagged but here is the reason - you need to share what you have done on this site and where you are stuck so that people can help you. So you can update your question to show where you are stuck instead of asking the full implementaion.

Comment: Please read here about [asking homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/1220550)

Answer (score 0):

```
Example in Java 

    int[] list1 = sumOfNext(new int[]{1,6,8,5,9,4,7,2});
    should print [1, 14, 18, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    
    int[] list2 = sumOfNext(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8});
    should print [1, 5, 15, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0]


    public static int[] sumOfNext(int[] arr) {
                if(arr.length == 0) {
                    return null;
                }
                int counter = 0;
                int[] result = new int[arr.length];
                int size = 1;
                int start = 0;
                int end = 0;
                while((end - start) <= size) {
                    int sum = 0;
                    while(start < arr.length && start <= end && end - start < arr.length){
                        sum += arr[start];
                        start++;
                    }
                    size++;
                    end = end + size;
                    result[counter] = sum;
                    counter++;
                }
                return result;
            }
```